# Express $\sin 4\theta$ by formulae involving $\sin$ and $\cos$ and its powers.

Tags: trigonometry, periodic-functions

I have an assignment question that says "Express $\sin 4\theta$ by formulae involving $\sin$ and $\cos$ and its powers."

I'm told that $\sin 2\theta = 2 \sin\theta \cos\theta$ but I don't know how this was found.

I used Wolfram Alpha to get the answer but this is what I could get :
$$
4\cos^3\theta\sin\theta- 4\cos\theta \sin^3\theta
$$

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: What are the little boxes with 00 on the top line and 12 on the bottom line?

Comment: Should be theta (I don't see the boxes, just theta)

Comment: If you don't know how $\sin2\theta=2\sin\theta\cos\theta$ was found, then what do you know about trig identities? Surely this question didn't come out of the blue --- you must know something about trig identities?

Comment: Do you know the formulas $\sin(a+b)=\sin(a)\cos(b)+\cos(a)\sin(b)$ and $\cos(a+b)=\cos(a)\cos(b)-\sin(a)\sin(b)$?   You can get the double angle formulas from them by letting $a=b$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Note that this method is pretty explanatory and slow, you can do it faster).

Let $u = 2\theta$, then we have:

$$ \sin 4\theta = \sin 2u $$

We know that:

$$ \sin 2u = 2\sin u\cos u$$

Now put $u = 2\theta$ back in:

$$ \sin (2 \cdot 2\theta) = 2\sin 2\theta \cos 2\theta $$
$$ \sin (4\theta) = 2\sin 2\theta \cos 2\theta $$

We know that $\sin 2\theta = 2\sin\theta\cos\theta$, so:
$$ \sin (4\theta) = 4\sin \theta \cos \theta \cos 2\theta $$

Still, we must get rid of that pesky $\cos 2\theta$. You should know the other double angle sum formula for $\cos$:

$$\cos 2\theta = \cos^2 \theta - \sin^2 \theta$$

So:

$$ \sin (4\theta) = 4\sin \theta \cos \theta \left( \cos^2 \theta - \sin^2 \theta \right)$$

$$ \sin (4\theta) = 4\sin \theta \cos^3 \theta - 4\sin^3 \theta \cos \theta$$

Answer (score 2):

The trigonometric identity $\sin 2\theta = 2\sin \theta \cos \theta$ or the more general one $\sin(\alpha + \beta) = \sin \alpha \cos \beta + \cos \alpha \sin \beta$ can be proved from the definitions of the functions $\sin$ and $\cos$ if that's what you are wondering. Classically, they are defined geometrically with a perpendicular triangle or a unit circle in a coordinate plane. However, to rigorously define it, $\sin$ and $\cos$ are defined in terms of integrals (See a good calculus books by Spivak, Apostol, Courant etc). After the sum of angles identity is proved from the definition, you just have to use it twice along with the identity $\cos 2\theta = \cos^2 \theta - \sin^2 \theta$. But for your assignment question, I don't think you have to prove the double angle identities.

Answer (score 1):

That's a trig identity.

So...

$\sin{4\theta} = 2\sin{2\theta}cos{2\theta}$

Can you take it from there?

Comment: How did you arrive at that? Can you please do it step-by-step?

Comment: It's an identity you need to memorize.

Comment: @AdegokeA $\sin 4\theta = \sin [2(2\theta)]$