# Calculating $\sin4\theta$ Given $\sin\theta=\frac{\sqrt{4-x}}{\sqrt{2}}$

Tags: trigonometry

I am near the end of solving an integral, and am left with the expression $\sin4\theta$. 
I am trying to solve the above expression with the given information but am not sure if I am doing this the best way... consider,
$$\sin\theta=\frac{\sqrt{4-x}}{\sqrt{2}}\rightarrow\theta=\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{4-x}}{\sqrt{2}}\right)\rightarrow4\theta=4\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{4-x}}{\sqrt{2}}\right)\rightarrow\sin\left(4\theta\right)=\sin\left(4\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{4-x}}{\sqrt{2}}\right)\right)$$

Is the above a correct manipulation, is there a better or more simplified way to do this?

Comment: Note you could also use something like what's asked & shown in [Express $\sin 4\theta$ by formulae involving $\sin$ and $\cos$ and its powers.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/323094/602049).

Comment: Thanks, that will greatly simplify my answer and makes sense

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $\sin\theta=\sqrt{2-x/2}$,$$\cos\theta=\pm\sqrt{1-\sin^2\theta}=\pm\sqrt{x/2-1},$$so$$\sin2\theta=2\sin\theta\cos\theta=\pm\sqrt{(4-x)(x-2)}.$$But $\cos2\theta=1-2\sin^2\theta=x-3$, so$$\sin4\theta=2\sin2\theta\cos2\theta=\pm2(x-3)\sqrt{(4-x)(x-2)}.$$We can't fix the sign because $\sin(\pi-\theta)=\sin\theta,\,\sin4(\pi-\theta)=-\sin4\theta.$

Answer (score 0):

If You somewhat know in which quadrant $\theta$ is in,

$$
\begin{aligned}
\cos{\left(\theta\right)}&=\pm\sqrt{1-\sin^{2}{\left(\theta\right)}}\\
&=\pm\frac{\sqrt{x-2}}{\sqrt{2}}
\end{aligned}
$$

We can now use trigonometry identity

$$
\begin{aligned}
\sin{\left(4\theta\right)}&=4\left(\cos^{3}{\left(\theta\right)}\sin{\left(\theta\right)}-\cos{\left(\theta\right)}\sin^{3}{\left(\theta\right)}\right)\\
&=\pm\left(6-2x\right)\sqrt{\left(4-x\right)\left(x-2\right)}
\end{aligned}
$$

These equations may come handy when dealing with trigonometry:

$$
\begin{aligned}
\cos{\left(n\theta\right)}&=Re\left(\left(\cos{\left(\theta\right)}+i\sin{\left(\theta\right)}\right)^{n}\right)\\
\sin{\left(n\theta\right)}&=Im\left(\left(\cos{\left(\theta\right)}+i\sin{\left(\theta\right)}\right)^{n}\right)
\end{aligned}
$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\cos2\theta=1-(4-x)=?$$

$$\cos4\theta=2\cos^22\theta-1=2(x-3)^2-1$$

$$\sin4\theta=\pm{1-\cos^24\theta}=?$$